# Sum of values in line chart

Tags: charts, sum, spotfire

I have a line chart by month on X axis and values on Y axis with a series by color.

I need to do the sum of values for each month on the same chart. I tried with a calculated column but I have a line by series.

I can do the job with hard-coding but the number of series is dynamic.

```
Max([Sum5003]) OVER (AllPrevious([Axis.X])) as [5003], 
Max([Sum5005]) OVER (AllPrevious([Axis.X])) as [5005],
Max([Sum5003]) OVER (AllPrevious([Axis.X])) +
Max([Sum5005]) OVER (AllPrevious([Axis.X])) as [total]
```

*I should not write python code.*

Best regards

Comment: we need sample data and expected output

Comment: I didn't found to do that without code.
I wrote python code powered by button to display or hide total values.